# How can I getElementByID with dynamic ID values?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem to `getElementById` of dynamic IDs. I need this value to make a random calculation of different elements.

**MY CODE**

```
<div class="col-lg-4" v-for="dado in dados">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" @click="rolagemD20">
      <p>{{dado.nome}}</p>
      <p v-bind:id="dado.nome">?</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

**MY FUNCTION:**

In these methods, I will get the ID and compare with the value, making different calculations for each ID

```
<script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                dados: [
                    { nome: 'D4' },
                    { nome: 'D6' },
                    { nome: 'D8' },
                    { nome: 'D10' },
                    { nome: 'D12' },
                    { nome: 'D20' }
                ]
            },
            methods: {
                rolagemD20: function () {
                    var valorAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1)
                    console.log(valorAleatorio)
                    document.getElementsById("").innerHTML = valorAleatorio
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what value you'd like to use. Might help if you'd translate your variable and value names to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Vue** you don't need to get the id of each element to set its HTML content, just you need to bind its value as below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dados: [
      { nome: 'D4', value: '' },
      { nome: 'D6', value: '' },
      { nome: 'D8', value: '' },
      { nome: 'D10', value: '' },
      { nome: 'D12', value: '' },
      { nome: 'D20', value: '' },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    // getting dado by reference to set his value with "valorAleatorio"
    rolagemD20: function(dado) {
      var valorAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
      dado.value = valorAleatorio
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-lg-4" v-for="dado in dados">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" @click="rolagemD20(dado)">
    <p>{{dado.nome}}</p>
    <p>{{ dado.value }}</p>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my life!